# Parameter array in SystemVerilog

Tags: parameter-passing, system-verilog

In systemverilog, it allows passing parameter array to lower module. Currently I have two .sv modules with parameters that use such feature. Below, `lowMod` is being instantiated in `uppMod`.

```
module lowMod #(parameter logic row [0:2], parameter logic col [0:1])
               (output logic a, input logic b);

     // main body of codes...

endmodule
```

and here's the uppMod.

```
module uppMod #(parameter logic row [0:4], parameter logic col [0:3])
               (output logic a, input logic b);

     lowMod #(row[1:3], col[0:1]) unit01 (.);
     lowMod #(row[1:3], col[2:3]) unit02 (.);

     // rest of codes...

endmodule
```

Constant values are assigned as parameters to the uppMod in testbench, and it works perfectly for behavioural simulation on Modelsim. But when I `read` it on DC Compiler, complaint pops up

> Syntax error at or near token ','. (VER-294)

It complains about the comma when declaring the parameter array. Presumably, I think DC uses VCS-like Verilog simulator (is that right?), and it seems, in contrast to Modelsim, DC doesn't like this syntax.

So is there anyway to make it work? I am actually doing something like this, where these arrays are initialised to some values...

```
module uppMod #(parameter logic row [0:4] = '{1,1,1}, parameter logic col [0:3] = '{1,1})
               (output logic a, input logic b);

     lowMod #(row[1:3], col[0:1]) unit01 (.);
     lowMod #(row[1:3], col[2:3]) unit02 (.);

     // rest of codes...

endmodule
```

so that when I elaborate the design on DC, my hope is to tune the parameters to the values I want, by

```
elaborate -library WORK -parameters "row[0:4]=>'{1,2,3,4,5}, col[0:3]=>'{1,2,3,4}"
```

But that doesn't work either.

> Error:  Syntax error in parameter value list at or near token '[0:4]' (string position 7). (VER-279)

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Tidus

Answer (score 0):

DC probably does not support an unpacked array as a parameter. Try making it an packed array of bits. As a packed array, you lose the strict type checking, but it should pass the values

Comment: I tried and the packed array didn't work either. I am trying something different, and will come back here to share with you guys later on once I figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts, it seems declaring the parameter logic internally within the module would do the job - simply declare them and initialise them with some values in the `lowMod`. In `uppMod`, we also do the same. But because we need to instantiate the `lowMod` with parametrized values, overriding is required in `uppMod`, and it works perfectly. In this way, we can avoid the said syntax error for both modules.

Hope this helps. Thanks.